# HTTP request in Emacs

Tags: emacs, lisp, elisp

I'm trying to send an HTTP GET request from my elisp code and store the contents of the response in a variable. As simple as

```
use LWP::Simple;
my $data = get("http://some.url");
```

I use Windows 7 & Emacs 24.2.

---

I tried using [Emacs-Web](https://github.com/nicferrier/emacs-web) package. Here's basically an example from the documentation, simplified even more:

```
(web-http-get
 (lambda (httpc header my-data)
   (message my-data))
 :url "http://breqwas.net/test.txt"))
```

That does not work, I get this response in minibuffer:

```
Keyword argument http://breqwas.net/emacs.txt not one of (:host :port :extra-headers :mode :logging)
```

The original piece of code from the documentation fails the same way.

---

I also looked at [http-get](http://cvs.savannah.gnu.org/viewvc/*checkout*/http-emacs/http-get.el?root=http-emacs) function, but "get URL in a buffer" - that's not what I need. I don't need it in a buffer, I need it in a variable.

Comment: I just installed the Web package from melpa, your example works fine. Make sure there is no older version of the package that gets in the way.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'd recommend using `url-retrieve-synchronously` that's included with Emacs.  The results are placed in a buffer, but you can easily evaluate it as a string like so:

```
(with-current-buffer (url-retrieve-synchronously "http://stackoverflow.com")
  (prog1
      (buffer-string)
    (kill-buffer)))
```

Comment: That looks like a damn crazy way of doing things, huh?

Comment: Embrace the emacs way of working with data in buffers and it's not so bad :)

Comment: BTW, that thing does not parse HTTP responce

Comment: @breqwas Well, you may want to ask yourself whether you really need a large amount of text stored in a string variable, or whether it might actually be more convenient to have it in a buffer, as the latter offers you a great variety of functions for processing the contents. Note that "in a buffer" does not necessarily mean that the contents are (immediately) visible to the user.